# Master Detail field not showing on VF page with custom controller

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page that is creating a record in Admin_Tracking__c. Their is a master detail field of Account on that object. For some reason the Account field won't show on my VF page. Anyone run into this issue before?

P.S. If I change the field to lookup instead of master detail the field displays as it should. I want to keep the field as master detail.

```
<apex:page Controller="Admin_Tracking_Controller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <style>
        //removed
    </style>

    <apex:form style="background-color:#D8DDE7;height:350px" >
        <div class="h1">
            Admin Time Tracking
        </div>
        <div class="b1">
            <apex:outputText >The Hub:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:outputText value="{!bcs.Name}" />
            <br/><apex:outputText >Activity:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Activity__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Account:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Account__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Carrier:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Carrier__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Time Utilized:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Time_Utilized__c}"/>
            <br/><apex:outputText >Notes:</apex:outputText>
            <br/><apex:inputField value="{!adminTracking.Tracking_Notes__c}" style="resize:none;height:50px;"/>
        </div> 

        <div class="b2" align="center" draggable="false" > 
            <apex:commandLink value="Save Time" action="{!save}" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" />
        </div> 

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class Admin_Tracking_Controller {

    public Admin_Tracking__c adminTracking { get; set; }
    public BCS__c bcs {get; set;}

    public Admin_Tracking_Controller() {
        bcs = [Select Id,Name FROM BCS__c WHERE User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];

    }

    public PageReference save() {

        try {
            upsert adminTracking;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('An exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Change apex:inputField to apex:outputField for Account

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: Santanu Boral's comment gave me an idea. Try checking your Master-Detail field to see if `Allow Re-Parenting` is checked. If it isn't, try checking it. I've no idea if this will work, but if it does, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Nope, field still doesn't show after setting reparenting property.

Comment: Whoops, Derek F, you found it. I hadn't changed the field back to an inputField. Once I did, your change made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular issue is the result of 2 factors:

1. You're trying to create an `Admin_Tracking__c` record (hence `Account__c` is blank)
2. Your `Account__c` field is a master-detail relationship field

**Why it isn't working**

By default, Master-Detail fields do not allow anyone to change the value contained in the field after it has been set once. This effectively makes the field "read-only". If you check the Field-Level Security (FLS) setting for a Master-Detail field, you'll see that the "read only" checkboxes aren't checked, but you also can't set/unset this for any profile.

Because it's effectively a read-only field, Salesforce sees no point in rendering the lookup field input + icon.

If a Master-Detail field is populated, and you use the field in an `<apex:inputField>` tag, Salesforce will simply render the value of the field. In your case, since there is no value populated, this simply shows up as a blank field.

**Making things work the way you want them to**

You can change this by checking the `Allow reparenting` checkbox when you edit the field through the Salesforce web UI. Allowing reparenting changes the field to be editable.

You still can't do anything with the read-only checkbox if you try to edit FLS, so this effectively makes it read-write for everyone (you might be able to control this through some other mechanism, but I don't care to find out what that mechanism might be).

Since the field is now editable, Salesforce will render the input field box + lookup icon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set reparenting as true. The only thing you need to do is that initialize the variable as

adminTracking = new Admin_Tracking__c ();

in constructor. This will resolve your issue even without setting reparenting as true

Thanks